# Cannot save MS Access module after running action query

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I have this code somewhere in MS Access 2019 database module:

```vb
    BeginTrans
    DBEngine(0)(0).Execute "delete from table1 where field1=""value1"""
    CommitTrans
```

After running this code, I cannot save any database document object: module, form or report.
When try to save, one of two message options appears:

1. Microsoft Access cannot save design changes or save to a new database object because the file is open by another user.
   To save design changes or save to a new object, you must have exclusive access to the file.
2. You do not currently have exclusive access.
   If you keep making changes, you won't be able to save them later.

I tried to use `currentdb()` instead of `DBEngine(0)(0)` but with no success.
Only `docmd.runsql` works as it should, but it is not the preferred method for executing queries.

Also tried to use refresh method  of `workspaces`, `databases`, `tabledefs` collections with no success.

I had no such issue in earlier versions of Access (2003 and earlier).

Is this known problem and how to resolve it?

**Update**
Solved it. Splitted the database into frontend/backend and the problem went away.

(But it seems as a kind of bug)

Comment: Are you sure it is related to this code? That is not a design change.

Comment: Yes, I traced this code with debugger and the ability to save the document disappears immediately after the query is executed (which really deletes some records from the table)

Comment: Really, saving design objects (modules, forms, reports) is not something that you should be mixing up with "running" code or "deployed" code, and still (to me) seems to have little or nothing to do with this query. I suspect there is more here. But in any case you should be splitting your front end/back end and for lots of good reasons.

Comment: I have never seen DBEngine(0)(0).Run used like this. Use CurrentDb.Execute.

Comment: @June7 Of course Execute method, not Run, just typo, thanx. As for using CurrentDB instead DBengine(0)(0) - it doesn't matter in my case.

CurrentDB() is Access.Application method which always creates new DAO.Database object (`CurrentDB is CurrentDB` is always  false). May  be Access do some extra work with it during object's lifetime.

In contrast  DBengine(0)(0) is always a reference to the same single object, directly obtained from the DAO library and created when app started.


Changing one to another doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @topsail I agree with you about splitting. I just haven't had time yet, this is just a new project under development. 

And yes, it seems to me too manipulating with regular data in tables should not somehow influence on design objects (which in turn by self are data in system tables).

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to qualify transaction methods, and run queries in the same context where you opened the transaction.

E.g.

```
With DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    .BeginTrans
    .Databases(0).Execute "myQuery"
    .CommitTrans
End With
```